# Execute Javascript Function Inside Specific Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to execute javascript function - onload only in specific div, but I'm stuck, so if someone can help me, please. Thank you very much in advance

```js
function dropsFall() {

}
```

```css
.drop {
  display: block;
  min-height: 280px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl drop"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you meant actually

Comment: welcome to stack overflow , you want to execute function when `div` clicked ? please search about it then post your question.

Comment: Thanks for the welcome :)
I'm ashamed from this question at all but ....
Actually, no. The function is an animation of shapes and color changing, which is now executing all over the page, not at the specific place/div where I want it to be.

Comment: It's unclear what you're asking for ,what do you want exactly  , execute function on div ? on click , on drag , drop ??

Comment: bRIMOs - onload

Comment: @xx5ko could you post the whole code of annimation here

Comment: @xx5ko  could you post the whole code of  animation  here

Answer (score 1):

This snippet of code performs an animation inside a specified div (that acts like a container):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Page Title</title>

</head>
<body>
<style>
.rectangle
{
   width: 300px;
   height: 20px;
   display: block;
   position: relative;
   border: 1px solid black;
   margin: 20px 0;
}

.square-small
{
   display: block;
   width: 20px;
   height: 20px;
   position: absolute;
   background-color: green;
}
</style>
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-BbhdlvQf/xTY9gja0Dq3HiwQF8LaCRTXxZKRutelT44="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

  <script>
  $('body').ready(function(){
    $('.rectangle')
   .find('.square-small')
   .animate({
      left: $('.rectangle').width() - $('.rectangle').find('.square-small').width()
    }, 'slow');});
</script>

<div class="rectangle">
   <div class="square-small"></div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you want to add drop class in div on click event ?

```
<div class="row">
     <div class="col-xl" onclick="dropsFall(this)"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: explain your requirement exactly.

Answer (score 0):

Pass your div ID to the function as a parameter and use if statement to check if it is the required div or not

```
function dropsFall(my_div) {
   if(my_div==‘your required div’){
       //your code will be here
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Then why not write your script inside your `div` like following:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xl drop">
  <script>dropsFall()</script>
  </div>
</div>
```